# Cannot find org.springframework.integration.Message when using spring-boot-starter-integration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm using Spring boot and want to use the starter pom for Spring Integration.

In my POM I have:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This pulls in 4.3.6 versions of Spring Integration jars and 4.3.5 of Spring Framework jars. In one of my own classes I'm trying to use Message:

```
import org.springframework.integration.Message;

public Object doThings(Message<?> message) {
}
```

but I can't seem to locate Message. In an older version of Spring integration it was in spring-integration-core.jar but it's not there in this version. Has it moved or has something changed? I've checked the docs and it's still referenced so I assume I'm looking in the wrong place - but core sounds like the place it should be in to me! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it really __org.springframework.integration.Message__, or should it be __org.springframework.messaging.Message__? See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/spring-integration-3.0-to-4.0-migration-guide

Comment: @Tome - you are indeed correct, thanks very much! I should have spotted this myself, if I'd bothered to look at any of the Spring Integration classes I would have seen it. Thanks for the link too. If you turn this into an answer rather than a comment I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few core concepts of Spring Integration have been merged inside Spring Core between versions 3.0 and 4.0, and `org.springframework.integration.Message` is one of them.

In your code sample, replacing

```
import org.springframework.integration.Message;

public Object doThings(Message<?> message) {
}
```

by

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

public Object doThings(Message<?> message) {
}
```

will do the trick.

For a more exhaustive list of affected classes and interfaces, have a look at [the 3.0 to 4.0 Spring Integration migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/spring-integration-3.0-to-4.0-migration-guide)

Answer (score 1):

It ok for me with using this version

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
<version>4.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
```